# It's possible to get the Scaffold's body height and width?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to set dynamic sizes to the widgets that I implement in my application, I'm currently using:

```
MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/height
```

which gives you the size of the screen, but I need the widgets to be based on the size of the scaffolding body and not the full screen

Answer (score 17):

You can user a Builder for your Scaffold:

```
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(),
  body: Builder(
    builder: (context) {
      return Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
```

And then:

```
bodyHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - Scaffold.of(context).appBarMaxHeight
```

At least, I found the solution in that way.

Comment: Thanks! `...  - Scaffold.of(context).appBarMaxHeight` is the only thing that actually helped me placing SingleChildScrollView correctly without making it actually scrollable (RefreshIndicator use case).

Comment: I could use Scaffold.of(context).appBarMaxHeight even without using a Builder

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can do it with a layoutBuilder widget. Check this:

https://medium.com/@KarthikPonnam/flutter-layoutbuilder-widget-1-b09fd1e6907f

Answer (score 4):

Here is the how you can get Scaffold body height correctly

Firstly, get the **AppBar height**. You need to use variable for it.

```
var appBar = AppBar(
      title: Text('Testing'),
    );
```

Now, **follow** the below code [**which is basically=> Total Height - AppBar's height - Padding present on the top(App status bar's height )**]

```
final bodyHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height -
                  -appBar.preferredSize.height -
                  MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top
```

**How to use it?** Let say you have Column with 2 child

```
Column(children: [
        Container(
          height: bodyHeight * 0.7,
          child: ...,
        ),
        Container(
          height: bodyHeight * 0.3,
          child: ...,
        ),
      ],
)
```

Comment: Didn't work for me. Still got the overflow error.

Comment: Post your code to so that one can understand the context or scenario where you are stucked.

Answer (score 0):

You could also subtract the height of the appbar from MediaQuery.of(context).size.height

Answer (score 0):

Just simply do this to get the size (height in this case) of your Scaffold Body alone.

```
final fullHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
final appBar = AppBar(); //Need to instantiate this here to get its size
final appBarHeight = appBar.preferredSize.height + MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top;
final scaffoldBodyHeight = fullHeight - appBarHeight;
```

**Note:** appBarHeight is the addition of the height of the appBar and the height of the device status bar.

**scaffoldBodyHeight** is the height of your scaffold body!

Answer (score 0):

use Material builder property like this

```
   scaffoldMessengerKey: Repository.messengerKey(context),
          scrollBehavior: AppScrollBehavior(PlatformInterface.appPlatform),
          builder: (context, child) {
            return Center(
              child: ConstrainedBox(
                constraints: BoxConstraints(maxWidth: 300, maxHeight: 600),
                child: child!,
              ),
            );
          },
```